# Using JavaCV Stitching for Android Phone

Tags: android, javacv

I Use JavaCV On Android 4.0.3 it run to error with

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) in unknown function, file C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 1432
```

Finding features...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:1432: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0
```

at `com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_stitching$Stitcher.stitch(Native Method)`

at `Lesson3_Stitch.main(Lesson3_Stitch.java:17)`

Anyone can teach me how to fix it ? Thank you.

this is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher.createDefault(true);
        MatVector images = new MatVector(2);
        images.put(0, cvLoadImage("sample1.png"));
        images.put(1, cvLoadImage("sample2.png"));

        IplImage result = new IplImage();

        int status = stitcher.stitch(images, images);

        if (status != Stitcher.OK) {

            cvSaveImage("result.png", result);
            System.out.println("cant stitch image" + status);

        }

        result = cvLoadImage("sample1.png");

        final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("My Image", 1);

        // Request closing of the application when the image window is closed.
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Show image on window.
        // canvas.showImage(result);

    }

    private static void cvSaveImage(String string, IplImage result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private static IplImage cvLoadImage(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why in hell does that compile? javax.swing .JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE there is no swing in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import OpenCV for Android however you code cannot work due you use a custom function for cvLoadImage which returns null. This cannot work.

You could try to use CV.loadImage or some variations. Right now I have no OpenCV installation for testing.

Comment: I import opencv4android but I have no idea how to use CV.loadimage.Can you just teach some example code for me? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you I see that JavaCV does work in another way like OpenCV 2.0 in c/c++. Your syntax seems to be correct as I googled it now but I have no idea where this funcrions come from. You could also try something like `IplImage.loadImage`, but however I don't know it. Sorry again.

Comment: I found some references for `Mat img = new Mat(); Highgui.imwrite(img, "/mnt/sdcard/image.png");` you could try that however this is not `IplImage`.

Comment: problem is The method put(long, opencv_core.CvArr) in the type opencv_core.MatVector is not applicable for the arguments (int, Mat)

look's like images.put(0, cvLoadImage("sample1.png")); is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you 2 things:

Firstly, check that you have the correct imports:

`import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;`

`import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.MatVector;`

`import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_stitching.Stitcher;`

`import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;`

(Sorry, I don't know why I cannot put them without the space between lines).

Secondly, put the complete path of the picture. It happened to me when it didn't find the image.

```
images.put(0,cvLoadImage("/storage/sdcard0/Download/testpicture.JPG"));
```